# Bake driver to keyframes

Tags: animation, drivers

Can you bake the animation created from a driver to keyframes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Select the object and press *Bake Action* in *3D view > Header > Object* (or *Pose* if you are baking an armature from pose mode) *> Animation*:

[image]

Comment: somehow when I bake my animation with driven properties, it doesn't work. I have a root bone which has a "Follow Path" constraint on it. then I have 4 more bones that are driven by the offset_factor from that constraint. when I bake my Animation. It bakes the offset_factor correctly but not the rotation of the other 4 bones. do you know why?

Comment: I wonder if this solution no longer works?  I tried it for [another question: convert/bake driver in shape key](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/285662/is-there-some-way-to-bake-shape-key-driver-results-to-keyframes) and it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. there is an import export format called .mdd, which i think you can enable in preferences tab under addon menu.
select the mesh you want to bake the animation for, click export, select .mdd, then inside blender, copy the mesh you just exported, delete every modifier or drivers or anything that influences the animation. import the .mdd file. and you will have all the animations baked into your mesh.