# Enable Inherit Rotation but keep visual rotation?

Tags: animation, export

I just finished an animation where I had the "Inherit Rotation" on the head-bone unchecked because it's easier to animate like that.

Now I want to export the animation and I have a problem: the format I export the animation to doesn't support this setting.

Is there a way/a script that can compute keyframes that have to be added/modified to toggle "Inherit Rotation" on without changing the visual transformation of the bone?

Comment: What about baking the animation? See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8164/599

Comment: That works but is unfavorable because it often adds many unneeded keyframes making the output file bigger than it needs to be (~20-100 more keyframes)

Comment: You could clean the keyframes in the graph editor (header > key > clean) afterwards, to try and get rid of the extras

Comment: In that case it's easier to readjust the bone's RotLocScale yourself, imo.

Comment: It's automatic, not sure if that was clear in my previous comment..