# Baked animation actions - what do the settings mean?

Tags: animation, baking

The file has a camera following a path, and it tracks to an empty that was keyframed at various points on the timeline. It scrubs fine for me, but when  it was rendered on SheepIt, the camera stayed fixed on where the empty started. After looking [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8165/7548) and consulting in their chat, I baked the action of the empty and tried again. In the screenshot is the settings used.

[image]

I don't know what any of those settings mean, and there doesn't seem to be a manual page. In fact, searching about this doesn't turn up much.

I'd like to read or find out more about this, is there a resource out there?

Edit: I'd checked the previous version when I said that the re-render was doing the same thing, in fact it hasn't quite finished yet. My bad, sorry. Still, I really would like to understand a little what I'm doing.